# java HOUR_OF_DAY different on different systems

Tags: java

I have same Java code running on Windows and Solaris machines. There is part of code that produces different results:

```
Calendar cd = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int off = cd.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/3600/1000;
System.out.println("current hour " + hour + ", zone offset " + off);
```

If I run this code at 16:15 localtime, Windows machine returns 16 as hour and zone offset as 2 (I am in GMT+2 time zone and daylight saving is on at the moment). On Solaris I get 15 as hour and same zone offset. "date" command on Solaris shows that time is correct and shows right time zone. Solaris runs Java 1.4 and Windows runs 1.5, although I'm not sure if that makes any difference. Any ideas why results are different?

Comment: Write once, run anywhere? `:P`

Comment: If you run the `date` command on the Solaris machine, what is the output?  (more importantly, is that correct)

Answer (score 4):

I would guess one machine is not configured for dayligth saving.

Querying the field `Calendar.DST_OFFSET` should return  daylight savings offset in milliseconds.

Comment: Thats seems to be the case. Windows returns 3600 seconds and Solaris 0. Just wondering what Java uses to get this offset? Unix shows correct date: Tuesday September 28 16:55:05 Lith DST 2010

Comment: I wonder if Solaris perhaps has a different start date to DST?  So the time on the Solaris box is actually off, but you don't realize it.  Does the box have automatic time correcting software on it, like ntpd?  It could have simply adjusted your clock by an hour for you without you realizing when the fake DST boundary hit.

Comment: Yes, we use ntpd on this box.

Comment: I tried to run this program on another Solaris machine, everything went fine. So it seems to be a problem of particular server's configuration (not a big surprise).

Comment: It seems pretty clear that something's screwy with the time on that machine.  Just out of curiosity, on the other Solaris machine, what is the output of the `date` command?

Comment: Machine runs in Lithuania so it's environment has TZ set to Europe/Vilnius. If I do `export TZ=EET` and run my program again, DST offset changes from 0 to 3600 and hour becomes correct. Another server which was working fine, had TZ set to EET.